# Get (or set) a customer group by group name

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

is there any way of getting (or setting) a customer group by group name? Something like loadByAttribute for customer groups or do i need to gell all customer groups and filter them by name?

Thanks,
Korkut

Answer (score 0):

Get the group id from group name

For filtering you can use
->addAttributetoFilter('group_id',..);

If you want to get a customer group id
Load the customer
$customer->getGroupID();

Comment: Well, I mentioned your solution in my question ("or do i need to gell all customer groups and filter them by name") but thanks anyway.